# Masking an Image with an Image?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Dont work with code:

```
    CGImageRef localResultImage;
    CGImageRef localMaskImage;

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(myImageMask);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(myImageMask);
    size_t bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(myImageMask);
    size_t bitsPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(myImageMask);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(myImageMask);
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(myImageMask);
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(myImageMask);
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGImageGetColorSpace(myImageMask);
    CGColorRenderingIntent intent = CGImageGetRenderingIntent(myImageMask);

    localMaskImage = CGImageCreate(width,
                                   height,
                                   bitsPerComponent,
                                   bitsPerPixel,
                                   bytesPerRow,
                                   space,
                                   bitmapInfo,
                                   provider,
                                   NULL,
                                   TRUE,
                                   intent);

    localResultImage = CGImageCreateWithMask(myImage, localMaskImage);

    CGContextDrawImage(myContext, dirtyRect, localResultImage);
```

localResultImage = (null) - Why?

In documentation Apple:
Instead of passing an image mask that’s created using the function CGImageMaskCreate,
you supply an image created from one of the Quartz image-creation functions.

Source samples of an image that is used as a mask (but is not a Quartz image mask) operate as alpha values.
....
In this case, assume that the image shown in Figure 11-6 is created using one of the Quartz image-creation functions, such as CGImageCreate.

**but does not work...Hmm**

*log Info myImageMask:

Width: 440

Height: 292

BitsPerComponent: 8

BitsPerPixel: 8

BytesPerRow: 440

BitmapInfo: 0

ColorSpace:  (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome; Dot Gain 20%)*
RenderingIntent: 2

Comment: +1 for nice looking code/font.

Comment: are myImageMask and myImage != null?

Comment: myImageMask == true / myImage == true / localMaskImage == true

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which can cause the problem is to have `myImage` as `null` in the following line. Rest all code looks good.

```
localResultImage = CGImageCreateWithMask(myImage, localMaskImage);
```

If myImage is an object of class UIImage then you should use below line:

```
localResultImage = CGImageCreateWithMask([myImage CGImage], localMaskImage);
```

Comment: myImage: <CGImage 0x10221f5e0>
myImageMask: <CGImage 0x10222ee90>
localMaskImage: <CGImage 0x10014b220>
localResultImage: (null)

Comment: myImage and all objects images is CGImageRef. All objects are perfectly displayed in the view, except - localResultImage.